# Error while deleting a vector pointer to pointers

Tags: c++, std

What do you think about this function?

```
void deleteVector(vector<Persistent*> *v) {
    if (v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < v->size(); i++)
            delete v[i];
        delete v; 
    }
}
```

I keep getting the following errors:

- test.cpp: In member function 'void Koala::ListAddressAction::deleteVector(std::vector >*)':
- test.cpp:160: error: type 'class std::vector >' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer
  test.cpp: In member function 'virtual void Koala::ListAddressAction::execute()':
- test.cpp:176: error: no matching function for call to 'Koala::ListAddressAction::deleteVector(std::vector >*&)'
- test.cpp:157: note: candidates are: void Koala::ListAddressAction::deleteVector(std::vector >*)

I think this is because I'm getting a reference from [] operator... but I don't know how to solve it...

Thank you...

Comment: The real question is do you really need both of those pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v` is a pointer, so you'll need to dereference it before using the subscript operator on it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v->size(); i++)
    delete (*v)[i];
//         ^^^^
```

Alternatively, you can use the explicit operator syntax:

```
delete v->operator[](i);
```

Answer (score 0):

`v` is the pointer you're passing in. When you do `v[i]` you are accessing the `i`th `vector`. Really, you only have one vector and you want to `delete` its elements. To do that, dereference the pointer first:

```
delete (*v)[i];
```