# Deleting <template> objects, error: type ‘class Circular_Buffer<unsigned int>’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer

Tags: c++, destructor

I'm trying to optimize this code for a Microchip Fubarino.
the original code:
https://gist.github.com/edwintcloud/d547a4f9ccaf7245b06f0e8782acefaa

```
delete cb; // error: type ‘class Circular_Buffer<unsigned int>’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
```

I tried many things, but nothing helped.

also

```
        printf("deleting buffer\n");
        for(uint32_t i = 0; i < max_size; i++)
            {
                //printf("deleting item %hhd\n", i);
                //printf("deleting item\n");
                delete (T*)buffer[i];//delete the A object allocations. // <-----
            }
```

returns a warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

witch i though to have found a solution here, although it enabled me to compile:
[Error while deleting a vector pointer to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137529/error-while-deleting-a-vector-pointer-to-pointers)

```
#ifndef CIRCULAR_BUFFER_H
#define CIRCULAR_BUFFER_H





// https://gist.github.com/edwintcloud/d547a4f9ccaf7245b06f0e8782acefaa

//===================================================================
// File: circular_buffer.cpp
//
// Desc: A Circular Buffer implementation in C++.
//
// Copyright © 2019 Edwin Cloud. All rights reserved.
//
//===================================================================

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// Includes
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <QCoreApplication>  // needed to use uint32_t

template <class T> class Circular_Buffer {
private:
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Circular_Buffer - Private Member Variables
    //---------------------------------------------------------------

    T* buffer; // using a smart pointer is safer (and we don't
    // have to implement a destructor)
    //size_t head = 0;             // size_t is an unsigned long
    //size_t tail = 0;
    //size_t max_size;
    uint32_t head = 0;             // size_t is an unsigned long
    uint32_t tail = 0;
    uint32_t max_size;
    T empty_item;// = 0x00; // we will use this to clear data
public:
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Circular_Buffer - Public Methods
    //---------------------------------------------------------------

    // Create a new Circular_Buffer.
    //Circular_Buffer<T>(char max_size)
    //    : buffer(unique_ptr<T[]>(new T[max_size])), max_size(max_size){};
    Circular_Buffer<T>(char max_size)
        : buffer(new T[max_size]), max_size(max_size){};
    //  buffer(std::make_unique<T[]>(max_size))
    //  std::unique_ptr<T[]>(new T[max_size]) // orginal

    ~Circular_Buffer<T>(){
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814188/c-array-of-pointers-delete-or-delete
        printf("deleting buffer\n");
        for(uint32_t i = 0; i < max_size; i++)
            {
                printf("deleting item %hhd\n", i);
                //printf("deleting item\n");
                //delete buffer[i];//delete the A object allocations.
            }
        buffer = NULL;
        delete[] buffer;
        this->head = 0;
        this->tail = 0;
        printf("detroyed\n");
    }

    // Add an item to this circular buffer.
    void enqueue(T item) {
        if(this->buffer == NULL){
            printf("Nothing to add\n");
            return;
        }
        // if buffer is full, throw an error
        //if (is_full()){
        //throw std::runtime_error("buffer is full");
        //}

        // insert item at back of buffer
        buffer[tail] = item;

        // increment tail
        tail = (tail + 1) % max_size;
    }

    // Remove an item from this circular buffer and return it.
    T dequeue() {
        if(this->buffer == NULL){
            printf("Nothing to remove\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        // if buffer is empty, throw an error
        //if (is_empty()){
        //throw std::runtime_error("buffer is empty");
        //}

        // get item at head
        T item = buffer[head];

        // set item at head to be empty
        // T empty_item;  // redunant, declared above
        buffer[head] = empty_item;

        // move head foward
        head = (head + 1) % max_size;

        // return item
        return item;
    }

    // Return the item at the front of this circular buffer.
    T front() { return buffer[head]; }

    // Return true if this circular buffer is empty, and false otherwise.
    bool is_empty() { return head == tail; }

    // Return true if this circular buffer is full, and false otherwise.
    bool is_full() { return tail == (head - 1) % max_size; }

    // Return the size of this circular buffer.
    char size() {
        if (tail >= head)
            return tail - head;
        return max_size - head - tail;
    }
};
#endif // CIRCULAR_BUFFER_H
```

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    
    
        Circular_Buffer<uint32_t> cb(10);
    
        printf("\n === CircularBuffer Test ===\n");
        printf("Size: %hhd\n", cb.size());
    
        uint32_t x = 1;
        printf("Enqueue 1, val: %d\n", x);
        cb.enqueue(x);
        printf("Size: %hhd\n", cb.size());
        x = 2;
        printf("Enqueue 1, val: %d\n", x);
        cb.enqueue(x);
        printf("Size: %hhd\n", cb.size());
        printf("Enqueue 1, val: %d\n", x);
        cb.enqueue(x);
        printf("Size: %hhd\n", cb.size());
        x = cb.dequeue();
        printf("Dequeue: %d\n", x);
        printf("Size: %hhd\n", cb.size());
        x = cb.dequeue();
        printf("Dequeue: %d\n", x);
        printf("Size: %hhd\n", cb.size());
        x = cb.dequeue();
        printf("Dequeue: %d\n", x);
        printf("Size: %hhd\n", cb.size());
        x = cb.dequeue();
        printf("Dequeue: %d\n", x);
        printf("Size: %hhd\n", cb.size());
        printf("Empty: %d\n", cb.is_empty());
    
        cb.~Circular_Buffer<uint32_t>();
        delete cb; // <------------------------------------------
    
        printf("start over\n");
        uint32_t y = 1;
        printf("Enqueue 1, val: %d\n", y);
        cb.enqueue(y);
        printf("Size: %hhd\n", cb.size());
        y = 2;
        printf("Enqueue 1, val: %d\n", y);
        cb.enqueue(x);
        printf("Size: %hhd\n", cb.size());
        y = 3;
        printf("Enqueue 1, val: %d\n", y);
        cb.enqueue(x);
        printf("Size: %hhd\n", cb.size());
    }
```

Comment: `buffer` is initialised in the constructor with the expression `new T[max_size]`.   So the only corresponding `delete` expression should be `delete [] buffer` (and that should be done exactly once for every usage of `new[]`).    It's all or nothing - you're trying to deallocate elements of buffer individually, which is invalid.

Comment: Side note: Try to avoid writing stuff like *I tried many things, but nothing helped.* It never helps.

Comment: @Peter i found this "for" loop design here on stack, when i searched how to delete a array of pointers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814188/c-array-of-pointers-delete-or-delete

Comment: @user4581301 that's what i did before posting the question and get answer like these.

Comment: @NaturalDemon That isn 't an array of pointers

Comment: @MikelF, well i assumed i had to clear all the elements before using delete[] bufffer and the QT creator compiler gave hints.

Comment: @MikelF it's for a micro processor, it shouldn't leak or so.

Comment: In your code, 'buffer' is a pointer to uint32_t. Not a pointer to pointers.

Comment: Also this:     cb.~Circular_Buffer<uint32_t>(); You never explicitly call a destructor. Never.

Comment: @MikelF it gives an error if i remove "(T*)" in the "destructor delete" loop, error: type ‘unsigned int’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer

Comment: @MikelF almost never. I've had to manually destroy a couple times to clean up after placement `new`.

Comment: @user4581301 Point taken. Placement new is not in my 'usual' area of focus.

Comment: As it should be.

Comment: @NaturalDemon - That link is for an array of pointers, each of which is the result of a `new` expression.  Your code is not working with such an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four problems with the code you have provided:

1. You are allocating a block of integers that you are trying to treat as an array of pointers.
2. You are explicitly calling the destructor for your class.
3. You are then calling delete which will then also call the destructor for your class.
4. You are using the pointer after it has been deleted.

When you instantiate your class with the type `uint32_t`, you are instructing the code to create a pointer to a contiguous memory space that is expected to contain elements of type `uint32_t`. These are not pointers. And based on the sample code, you did not want them to be pointers because you are not trying to queue pointers. Because these are **not pointers** you do not loop through to delete them. Even if they were pointers, you would be freeing the memory that they pointed to, not the memory that contains the address. When deleting an object that was created with `new []` you need to call `delete[]`. As Andy Coffin mentioned in a comment below, you should not set the buffer to `NULL` before deleting it.

Do not call a destructor directly. Unless you are doing things with placement `new` where you are 'placing' an item in a managed memory space where the default `delete` functionality would cause problems, you should never call a destructor directly. The `delete` method will call it for you.

Calling delete after erroneously calling the destructor will result in bad things. A double delete is not your friend. Furthermore, you do not call delete on a variable that is not a pointer. You did not dynamically allocate the `Circular_Buffer` object so `delete` is not appropriate.

Finally, if you HAD used a pointer to create your circular buffer object, you would be trying to access it after the deletion.

Another option you might consider is something like this:

```
template <class T, int S> class X {
    T buffer[S]; 
};
```

No allocations required.

Comment: One other point: the dtor for his circular buffer does: `buffer = NULL;  delete[] buffer;`. He really needs to get rid of the `buffer = NULL;` or at least move it after the `delete [] buffer;`, or else he'll leak the buffer.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Wow. I missed that. This could have been a coding test for a job candidate to spot the errors.

Comment: @MikelF that's just a test, to see if it's really gone, it's a microcontroller and shouldn't leak.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, yeah you could be right and i was doubting on that point, i viewed more on that on this site, it's just i recently picked up coding again and regressed to pretty much newby. : )

Comment: @MikelF, i have removed the loop in the destructor and all errors and warning are gone.
but one thing remains, i assume the memory has been returned or freed, how to delete the "cb" in INT main() witch was the origin of posting the question, the correct syntax for deleting the object.

Comment: @NaturalDemon Because `cb` is allocated on the stack (instead of as a pointer on the heap) it will be deleted when it goes out of scope. So once you hit the end brace '}' of main, destructors are called for all local variables.

Comment: @MikelF, this is just an test I'm running in QT creator, a bit better code editor than Arduino IDE, i might later on in the MCU explicitly delete it.  this new piece of code you gave me, where do you want me to put it? a new class, gives Shadow errors. thnx.

Comment: @NaturalDemon The new code snippet may be a bit too 'new' for the compiler you are using. It is a way to pass the size of the buffer as a template parameter so that it is fixed at compile time and avoids the allocation of heap memory.

Comment: @NaturalDemon And as for 'regressing to a pretty much newby', I am confident you'll be right back on top of things faster than you think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251229/discussion-between-naturaldemon-and-mikel-f).